# Getting page count in Word doc is not working using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to get the page count of a word file using java. I used poi jar 3.11 with the following code. when i used the below code am able to get word doc in 2003 format but while reading the page count it is throwing error as 
 ""

public class CreateDocumentFromScratch {

```
public static int pagesNo;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

    XWPFParagraph Paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    Paragraph.setBorderBottom(Borders.SINGLE);
    Paragraph.setBorderTop(Borders.SINGLE);
    Paragraph.setBorderRight(Borders.SINGLE);
    Paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
    Paragraph.setBorderBetween(Borders.SINGLE);

    XWPFRun Titleparagraph = Paragraph.createRun();
    Titleparagraph.setBold(true);
    Titleparagraph.setItalic(true);
    Titleparagraph.setFontFamily("Latha");
    Titleparagraph.setFontSize(10);
    Titleparagraph.setText("ஓட்டு எண்ணிக்கையில் புதிய முறை: முதல் முடிவு வெளியாக தாமதம் ஆகும்");

    XWPFRun Headlineparagraph = Paragraph.createRun();
    Headlineparagraph.setBold(true);
    Headlineparagraph.setItalic(true);
    Headlineparagraph.setFontFamily("Latha");
    Headlineparagraph.setFontSize(10);
    Headlineparagraph.setText("தமிழகத்தில் ஓட்டு எண்ணிக்கையின் போது புதிய முறை கடை பிடிக்கப்படுவதால், முதல் முடிவு வெளிவர தாமதம் ஆகும் என்று தலைமை தேர்தல் அதிகாரி பிரவீன்குமார் கூறினார்.");
    Headlineparagraph.addBreak();

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream("Sample.doc");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        document.write(outStream);
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    WordExtractor extractor = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Sample.doc");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateDocumentFromScratch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    HWPFDocument documentextract = null;
    try {
        documentextract = new HWPFDocument(fis);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateDocumentFromScratch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    extractor = new WordExtractor(documentextract);
    extractor = new WordExtractor(documentextract);
    String[] paragraphs = extractor.getParagraphText();

    int pageCount = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; ++i) {
        if (paragraphs[i].indexOf("\f") >= 0) {
            ++pageCount;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "pageCount --> "+pagesNo);
}
```

}

```
Error: 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:133)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:106)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore.verifyAndBuildPOIFS(HWPFDocumentCore.java:106)
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:174)
    at testapp.CreateDocumentFromScratch.main
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `WordExtractor` with `XWPFWordExtractor` and `HWPFDocument` with `XWPFDocument`. You can use `documentextract.getParagraphs()` to extract a list of`XWPFParagraph`.

Like this:

```
List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = documentextract.getParagraphs();
int pageCount = 1;
for (XWPFParagraph par :paragraphs) {
    if (par.getText().indexOf("\f") >= 0) {
        ++pageCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: XWPFWordExtractor  extractor = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
fis = new FileInputStream("Sample.doc");
 } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateDocumentFromScratch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        XWPFDocument documentextract = null;
        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = documentextract.getParagraphs();
        int pageCount = 1;
        for (XWPFParagraph par : paragraphs) {
            if (par.getText().indexOf("\f") >= 0) {
                ++pageCount;
            }
        } --> throws null pointer exception

Comment: i tried using the above code but it throws null pointer exception error

Comment: It will work please check why you are using "documentextract as null". please change it as document it will work for sure.